# Is it possible to perform style transfer on my own images?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, style-transfer

I have a set of around 60 fractals (e.g

[image: Fractal]

And a set of 60 snacks (e.g

[image]

And I want to apply the style of the fractal on the snack.

Is this possible? 
Or must I take specifically images from an existing data set with a pre-trained images model?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether the method involves training a model on style data or not.

At least [one method](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.06576) does not require that at all, instead training a network on a classification task and then infering the style of an image during the style transfer. So you can use a model that has been pre-trained on images that you do not have, and then use it and your images to perform the style transfers.

There is some ready-to use code to do that : [example](https://github.com/titu1994/Neural-Style-Transfer)

Comment: please see my response as an answer

Answer (score 1):

This is possible as trained images models are quite robust to extract the style and content of an image, though the strength/quality will defer depending on the model you choose.